# MVC Routing error on multiple form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem with an action inside an MVC controller. I have implemented a web form with two separate actions that works fine but present a problem. Here I report some portions of code I've used:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "STAMPA PREVENTIVO")]
public ActionResult SaveDetail(FormCollection values){
    //logic...
     var something = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("_printpdf") { FileName = filename + ".pdf", SaveOnServerPath = path };
     return something;
}

[HttpPost]
[MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "ACQUISTA")]
public ActionResult Checkout(FormCollection values)
{
    //logic...
    return View("_addressAndPayment");
}
```

Actually the first function that prints a pdf works fine and does its stuff perfectly. In the second one I have the problem that everything is executed fine but when I call the View() I get inside the view, render it and then I come back to the action inside the controller in an infinite loop (using debugger I correctly enter in the controller function and in the .cshtml page that contains some code, but then I go back to the controller without clicking anything or performing any sort of action). _addressAndPayment.cshtml is a simple page that actually does not contain a form and is placed in the Shared folder of the project. The main controller in which those functions are implemented is the HomeController. I assume this can be a sort of routing problem but I have some difficulties in finding out why this happens. Do you have any suggestions or explanations? And maybe a way to solve it?

Comment: Without seeing the View code, it's hard to know what's going on, but since you think it may be a routing problem - are you aware of this tool? https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: Thank you @jefftrotman. Nice tool, I've tested a little bit but even if the page is totally empty it returns the control to the action in the controller. I really cannot figure out what is going on in this page.